# Web Performance Test that requires login: How do you make it work in isolation and in load test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, webtest

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Load test, which contains a number of web performance tests.  Running the web performance tests requires you to be logged in to the website under test. Accordingly, the load test contains an initialization step - a small web performance test which does the log in, and which uses a plug-in to cache the cookie so obtained. The 'real' web performance tests - the ones that actually do the work also each have a plug-in that reads the cached cookie and adds it to the test, so that each test functions correctly:

```java
public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
{
    if (CookieCache.Cookies != null) // CookieCache is a static class of mine
        e.WebTest.Context.CookieContainer.Add(CookieCache.Cookies);
```

The problem is that while this all works absolutely fine when I run the load test, it means I can't run any of the web performance tests in isolation because if the load test initializer hasn't run then there's no cookie, so the web performance test won't be logged in and will fail.

Is there any recommended solution for this situation? In other words, if a web performance test needs to have logged in, is there any way to get it to run both in isolation and when it's part of a load test?

The obvious way to run each web performance test in isolation would be to have it call the login test first, but I can't do that because that'll be incorrect behaviour for the load test (where logging in should happen only once per user, right at the beginning of the load test).

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add the Login test to your individual web performance tests (via "Insert Call to Web Test"), but gated by a "Context Parameter Exists" Conditional Rule that looks for the *absence* of the context parameter **$LoadTestUserContext**.  That parameter only exists if the web test is running in a load test.

This way you get just one Login whether in or outside of a load test.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try and use the PreRequest Function instead of the PreWebTestFunction

```
Public Overrides Sub PreRequest(sender As Object, e As PreRequestEventArgs)
  MyBase.PreRequest(sender, e)
  Dim cookie As System.Net.Cookie = New System.Net.Cookie(...)
  e.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie)
```

That way both the Load test and the Web Test will work.

Comment: I did something along these lines some years ago.  It works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio 2010 Load Testing, but it sounds like you need the equivalent of NUnit's `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods which run once for all tests, whether you have selected a single test or all the tests in an assembly.

A [bit of searching](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vstswebtest/thread/ea7f340d-bf3d-4adc-a857-b056d7764019) implies that the equivalent is the `Init` and `Term` tests.

> 1) Right click on a scenario node in load test and select Edit Test
>   Mix...
>
> 2) In the edit test mix dialog, Look at the bottom the Form.  You will
>   see 2 check boxes.  One for an init test  and one for a term test.
>
> The init test will run prior to each user and term test will run when
>   user completes.  To make sure the term test runs, you also need to set
>   the cooldown time for a load test.  The cooldown time is a property on
>   the run setting node.  This setting gives tests a chance to bleed out
>   when duration completes.  You can set this to 5 minutes.  The cooldown
>   period does not necessarily run for 5 minutes.  It will end when all
>   term tests have completed.  If that takes 20 seconds, then that is
>   when load test will complete.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - much appreciated. Unfortunately your suggestion is basically what we're already doing. Adding an init test does as you say mean the web performance test will work correctly *when it's inside a load test* but doesn't solve the problem of getting the web performance test to always work, irrespective of whether it's inside a load test. That's because the Init test if load-test specific and so won't run if you run the web performance test outside the load test.